# Module not found in React - serialport error

Tags: reactjs, arduino, node-serialport

Hi everyone six month ago I was working designing a UI interface in a We development App with React. This was working fine, but now I run npm start and it show me a lot of errors.

I'm trying to load a React project. There are a lot of errors. The project is about an implementation with arduino and react. I connect the two arduinos via usb to my laptop and I just had to change the port and it ran.

I am working on windows but I don't know how to handle this error. I saw some post before and it says that serialport error will be solved with deleting node_modules folder and running npm install. but unfortunately I got thesame error. I really don't know how the backend works eventhough It used to run witouth problems, but here I post a the screenshots of the js file that has the problem.

Thanks for your help. I apreciate it.

Script with the problem

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('test3:server');
var http = require('http');

const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline');

const SERIAL_PORT_ARDUINO_PRINCIPAL = 'COM9';
const SERIAL_PORT_ARDUINO_SECONDARY = 'COM4';

const BAUD_RATE = 9600;

const serialPortArduinoPrincipal = new SerialPort(SERIAL_PORT_ARDUINO_PRINCIPAL, { baudRate: BAUD_RATE });
const serialPortArduinoSecondary = new SerialPort(SERIAL_PORT_ARDUINO_SECONDARY, { baudRate: BAUD_RATE });

const parserArduinoPrincipal = serialPortArduinoPrincipal.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\n' }));
const parserArduinoSecondary = serialPortArduinoSecondary.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\n' }));

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
*/

var server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  socket.on('WEB_TO_ARDUINO_PRIMARY', (from, msg) => {
    serialPortArduinoPrincipal.write(from, (err, results) => {
      console.log('err ' + err);
    });
  });

  socket.on('WEB_TO_ARDUINO_SECONDARY', (from, msg) => {
    serialPortArduinoSecondary.write(from, (err, results) => {
      console.log('err ' + err);
    });
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    io.emit('user disconnected');
  });
});

parserArduinoPrincipal.on('data', data => {
  io.emit('ARDUINO_PRINCIPAL', { data });
  console.log('ARDUINO_PRINCIPAL:', data);
});

parserArduinoPrincipal.on('error', data => {
  console.log('ARDUINO_PRINCIPAL:', data);
});

parserArduinoSecondary.on('data', data => {
  io.emit('ARDUINO_SECONDARY', { data });
  console.log('ARDUINO_SECONDARY:', data);
});

parserArduinoSecondary.on('error', data => {
  console.log('ARDUINO_SECONDARY:', data);
});

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lppsM.png)

Comment: How does this related to `Arduino` that you tagged?

Comment: Im using two arduinos conected to my laptop